# "You're not trying to find a Chinese angle on it, are you?" What may be the situation to ask this question?

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms

I came across this [here](https://www.miskatonic.org/slang.html).

Although the definition of "Chinese angle" is "a strange or unusual twist or aspect to something", and because there's no any context for the example question, but there is the preposition "on" before "it", I need a suggestion for the possible missing context (in order to fully understand how, when and where I might use the phrase, should I feel like doing it).

As for me, I think that it might be that someone is examining something, twisting it in his hands,  for a long time, and the other one, getting bored, may say: "Well, now! Are you trying to find a Chinese angle on it?" (meaning some invisible defect).

Please, correct me if I'm wrong with my guess.

Comment: I don't know whether the question is OT or not, but the expression is from Dashiell Hammett's _The Thin Man,_ and it might have been current among the hard-boiled folks of the 20's and 30's, or Hammett might have created it out of whole cloth. In any case, a great book and worthy of reading!

Comment: @P.E.Dant - I read his Glass Key years ago, and I've had The Thin Man on my must read list since then. Now that you mentioned it, I think I'll take it out from my bookcase. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Stop screwing around and go directly to _The Maltese Falcon!_

Comment: I've already had both the pleasure of reading it and listening to the audiobook. I like Peter May's Lewis trilogy very much.

Comment: By the way, a "Chinese angle," Hammett means an unexpected or innovative perspective. The inference is that, as Chinese is written from right to left, a "Chinese" perspective is similarly orthogonal to the commonplace, and might reveal something which was previously overlooked in conventional thinking.

Comment: As a side note: questions are put on hold *so that* they can be edited and reopened. If they are edited before that, that's nice, but not really required, and if the last close voter or two thinks the edit is not enough, the question may be left closed with fewer voters than if it had gone through the reopen queue — that is, less rigorously and with less of a chance.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - As soon as "angle" may mean a biased way of looking at something and "perspective" - a way of regarding situation, your comments are very close to being turned into an answer, just for me to fully understand what I want to and mark the question as answered. Could you do that, please?

Comment: @NathanTuggy - Thanks for the edit; I did need the explanation you gave.

Comment: I would be happy to do that, but my answer is only an _interpretation,_ and not an _answer_ as we use the term here, unfortunately!

Comment: @P.E.Dant: If you have a guess, it's best to put it in an answer so it can be judged, rather than leaving it in comment limbo where no one knows how reliable it is.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - But it would help me a lot to understand the meaning of the expression!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "Chinese angle," Hammett refers here not to any defect, but rather to an unexpected or innovative perspective. The inference is that, just as Chinese is written from right to left (instead of left to right as in English) a "Chinese" perspective is similarly orthogonal to the commonplace, and might reveal something which was previously overlooked in conventional thinking.

There is also in the expression, perhaps, a trace of the then-common cultural bias against Chinese immigrants to the United States, and of the perception that they lived separate from "real" Americans and that their thinking, just as their perceived way of life, was "different."

A modern reflection of this perception and bias is immortalized in the last line of Roman Polanski's *Chinatown:*

> [Forget it, Jake. It's Chinatown.](https://www.getyarn.io/yarn-clip/b09583b2-b07d-43b9-92c9-0e5b3446855c)

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! Now I need to find the context in the book, which is in front of me right now. If only you could direct me to the chapter!

Comment: Dashiell Hammett, The Thin Man, chapter 25:“You’re not trying to find a Chinese angle on it, are you,” he complained, “just because they shoot like that?”
“No, but any kind of angle would help some."

Comment: It's not only a US concept. The cricket term "Chinese cut" (less used now because of political correctness) basically means the batsman mishit the ball but got lucky. And a "Chinaman" is an unorthodox (but intentional) method of bowling which makes the ball swing the opposite way from what is expected - though the origin of that that term is attributed to a particular player from the West Indies in the 1930s, who was of Chinese descent.

Comment: Indeed. We have [something similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_home_run) in baseball. (You know - the manly sport upon which the incomprehensible game of cricket is based?) /me dodges brickbat...

Comment: Note: "/me" is an old school [IRC](http://www.livinginternet.com/r/ra_action.htm) reference. In IRC, if a user types "/me" the chat client will render [username]. So "/me dodges brickbat" would be rendered on the screen as "P.E.Dant dodges brickbat." The usage "/me" is also seen elsewhere, such in Usenet, as a sort of "in joke" employed by aficionadi.